# Powershell User Issue Through SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2012

I am currently trying to run a `Powershell` script through `SQL Server Agent`, which completes its task without error if I run it through `Powershell ISE` on the desktop.  The simple script is below (it's only being used for testing):

```
$test = "G:\test.txt"

if (Test-Path $testFile)
{
    Remove-Item $test
}
```

When I run this through SQL Server Agent, it produces a successful output - no errors whatsoever, but does show that it's being run as a different user in the job history log, for instance `domain\localmachine`, whereas when I run the script through Powershell ISE, it shows `domain\you`.

As a note, I can't confirm this manually because what I tried to do was run the below script both locally and through SQL Server Agent in a job to see the output, but the job failed (and thus why I suspect it's a user issue).  Therefore, I'm trusting SQL Server Agent as to the domain\locallmachine is running the job (the reason it won't delete the file).

```
([Environment]::UserDomainName + "\" + [Environment]::UserName) | out-file pssaved.txt
"$env:userdomain\$env:username" | out-file -append pssaved.txt
[Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name | out-file -append pssaved.txt

## Locally this produces domain\you
## On SQL Server Agent, I receive the error: The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Path SQLSERVER:\pssaved.txt does not exist. Please specify a valid path.'
```

Is there a way, through SQL Server Agent to run a job as my domain user, for instance domain\you instead of the domain\localmachine (at least, this would eliminate this possibility of an error)?

Comment: You can use the -Credential parameter on remove-item, but that would involve storing a set of credentials in the procedure script.

Comment: Is there a typo here?  The error text says `SQLSERVER:\psaved.txt` but your script specifies `pssaved.txt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a proxy for this. [Check it out.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: This works for building a proxy (and this link helps: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1199/sql-server-agent-proxies/) and it will execute as the appropriate account.  Unfortunately, this still won't delete the local file, so still look for that issue.